# Adding an element to a group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-extensions

I have a abelian group $(G,+)$, and element $a \in G$ and some positive integer $n$.

I would like to add an element $b$ to $G$ such that $nb=a$. To be more precise, I want to construct an Abelian group $G'$ such that $G$ is a subgroup of $G'$ and $G'$ has an element $b$ such that
$nb=a$.

**What I am thinking** Consider
$$
G':= G \times \{0,1,2, \ldots, n-1 \}
$$
with the operation
$$
(g,k) \oplus (h, m)= \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
(g+h, k+m) & \mbox{ if } k+m <n \\
(g+h+a, k+m-n) & \mbox{ if } k+m \geq n \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
This looks like adding the 2-digit "numbers $gk+hm$ with carrying.

My intuition tells me that $(G', \oplus)$ is indeed a group, and then $b=(0,1)$ has the desired property.

But it looks painfull to show that $G'$ is a group, and I would be surprised if this operation is not known ( maybe in the context of semi-direct products?).

**Question** Is this construction known? If yes, what is a good reference for it?

*P.S.* I think I've seen something like this in a group theory course I took more than 20 years ago, but not sure :)

Comment: For example, you have the integers $\mathbb Z_m^+,$  And we add a fraction $\frac {a}{n}$ to the mix.  $n (\frac {a}{n}) = a.$  Our new group is isomorphic to the group $\mathbb Z_n^+$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try
$$G'=\frac{G\oplus\mathbb{Z}}{\left<\left(a,-n\right)\right>}.$$
In fact, we can define an embedding $\phi:G\rightarrow G'$ by
$$g\mapsto \left\{(g,0)+k(a,-n):k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\},\quad \text{i.e. 
}\;g\mapsto\overline{(g,0)},$$
and we will have
$$\phi(a)=\overline{(a,0)}=n\cdot\overline{(0,1)}$$